# Unix : Redirection operator and Pipe operator related commands in SFTP

Tags: shell, unix, sftp, sshpass

How to work with redirection operator and Pipe operator related commands in SFTP?

Currently I have connected to **SFTP** via **SSHPASS** as below

```
[oouser@SVSATVMWHOST03-SITHPOO test]$ sshpass -e sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - backup_sftp@10.58.44.207:/Restore
Changing to: /Restore
pwd

sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /Restore
```

Again,

```
ls -ltr

sftp> ls -ltr

-rw-r-----    1 1500     1500     421782831 Jul 19 12:43 mOneBackup_IMS_20170719081701.tgz

-rw-r-----    1 1500     1500     374262100 Jul 24 11:54
mOneBackup_IMS_20170724010013.tgz
```

This is giving the output of ls -ltr result files located in sftp prompt, which is fine.

But,

I need a command to view / get the redirected output of ls -ltr with | (pipeline operation) and last 1 file name located in SFTP prompt

While sending the commands with pipe operator (|) in **SFTP** prompt  - server throws **"Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory"**

```
ls -ltr | tail -1

sftp> ls -ltr | tail -1

Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
Can't ls: "/Restore/|" not found**

[oouser@SVSATVMWHOST03-SITHPOO test]$
```

How to work with the pipe and redirection operation in SFTP prompt?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that "|" has no special meaning to the `sftp` "ls" command.

```
sftp> !ls -ltr | tail -1
```

Here, you're using the sftp "!" command to run a command on your local system. The rest of the line, `ls -ltr | tail -1`, is passed to your local shell. Sftp doesn't interpret the "|" in this line; your shell does. The only part of this that is special to sftp is the leading "!".

```
sftp> ls -ltr | tail -1
```

Here, you're using the sftp "ls" command to list information on remote files named "!", "tail", and maybe "-1". The error message that you get indicates that there's no remote file named "|".

As far as I can tell, the command-line `sftp` utility doesn't support redirection and piping for individual interactive commands.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Meanwhile, you have any idea that how to display the one very last modified file from sftp prompt. I need to take the one last most modified file for automation.